# Error message in terminal when using "-a"

Tags: node.js

I tried this command

```
ls -a -l ~/.ssh
```

but I got this error message,

```
Get-ChildItem : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'a' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: -Attributes -Directory -File -Hidden 
-ReadOnly -System.
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run a Linux command on a Windows machine because that's a Powershell error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried...?:

```
ls -la ~/.ssh
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.